# How to use JMSAppender log4j2 JAVA

Tags: java, jms, log4j2

I'm trying to push logs to an ActiveMqueue using JMS in log4j2.

I have done this in my log4j2.properites

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="5">
    <Appenders> 

        <RollingFile name="fishLogstash"
                fileName="E:/xxx/log/xxx.server/xxxLogstash.log" append="false"
                immediateFlush="false" bufferSize="1000"
                filePattern="/soft/log/xxx.server/xxxx-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100M" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>

        <JMS name="jmsQueue" destinationBindingName="logQueue"
                factoryName="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
                factoryBindingName="ConnectionFactory"
                providerURL="tcp://localhost:61616">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </JMS>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="fish" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

After this, I wonder how to use the JMS appender to log in my java code? How to retrieve this specific appender, is there somthing like

```
Logger log = Logger.getAppender("jmsQueue") ?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

In your property file, there are `xml` content. So I am assuming you are trying to use xml style property file. If so, rename your property file to have **`.xml`** extension. E.g. `log4j2.xml`. Remember to write log4j2 supported xml. Examples can be found [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html).

**2.**

Mention `name` value of your defined appenders as `AppenderRef` in `Loggers` section of property file. Based on your `Appenders` section, `Loggers` section can be

```
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="jmsLogger" level="warn">
        <AppenderRef ref="jmsQueue" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="warn">
        <AppenderRef ref="fishLogstash" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

**3.**

In your code, get JMS logger as follows:

```
Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("jmsLogger");
```

You can log whatever by using `log` variable. E.g.

```
log.info("some message");
```

Hope, this answer would help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked like a charm. One more thing, I can see now my messages in the Queue, but in the same time, this same log is written to STDOUT( Console). How can I avoid this ? because the cost of I/O is expensive.  I updated my post for this

Comment: In short, delete/comment "<AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />". But this will disable all console output through log4j.

Comment: However, I would suggest you to undo your last edit and post a new question mentioning your issues/expectations. This would increase your chance to get better solutions.